# Apache cert auth is not working

Tags: apache, authentication, ssl, certificate

I have set up a virtual host to serve as a Web API in my company and due to the use cases we have configured a Django app that makes basic auth in a URL path. It was required to use cert auth, so in apache's side we configured client cert verification on another URL but seems not to be working, apache is allowing all traffic to this URL location, the request headers remain the same as if no auth was requested by the server.

The conf file is like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    WSGIPassAuthorization on
    WSGIScriptAlias / /srv/www/site/site/wsgi.py
    Alias /favicon.ico /srv/www/site/static/img/favicon.ico
    Alias /static/ /srv/www/site/static/
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin http://127.0.0.1:9000

    SSLVerifyClient none
    SSLCACertificateFile ssl.crt/ClientCheck_CA.crt

    DocumentRoot /srv/www/site

    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>

    <Directory /srv/www/site>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Location /api-certauth/>
        SSLVerifyClient require
        SSLVerifyDepth 3
        SSLOptions +ExportCertData
    </Location>

    <Directory /srv/www/site/static>
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/

    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Basically, when I request http://server-name.com/api-certauth no auth was requested to my browser like any other URL in the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem, changed port 80 for 443